# OpenMP error: 'X' is predetermined 'shared' for 'private'

Tags: c, openmp

Does anyone know why the following code

```
void foo(const int X)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for private(X)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {  }
}
```

gives this error

> error: 'X' is predetermined 'shared' for 'private'

and how I can really make `X` private to each thread?

Comment: X is already `const` ... why do you want to make copies of it?

Comment: @pmg: Well it just happened to be `const` in what I was doing, but the same problem occurs for non-`const` variables... how do you fix those?

Comment: Are you sure you get the same error when X is not constant?

Comment: @csgillespie: My bad -- I removed the `const` qualifier from the wrong assignment in my code. (I had a variable named `rows` and also one named `_rows`, and removed it from the second one accidentally.) Thanks a lot! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: funny enough this issue is gcc specific. icc permits this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because `X` is constant. Just remove `const` and everything should work.

Comment: That's not a nice advice to make a constant into a mutable variable just to get rid of this message. The solution is: remove `private(X)`. `X` will default to `shared` then. Since `X` is a constant this is completely fine and save.